# jQuery add text to span within a div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="tagscloud">
       <span></span>
</div>
```

How would I do to add some text within the span like code below ?

`<span>**tag cloud**</span>`

**Edit**:
actually the span has an id

```
<div id="tagscloud"> <span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ2"></span> </div>
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#tagscloud span").text("Your text here");
```

The same code will also work for the second case. You could also use:

```
$("#tagscloud #WebPartCaptionWPQ2").text("Your text here");
```

Comment: yes but i need to take into account the div id also, because i have other span with the same id on this page.

Comment: @user472285 Elements shouldn't have the same IDs as each other - IDs on a page should be unique.

Comment: i know :( but i have no control on that. the developer made it this way...is there a way to target a span id within a div with an id?

Comment: You should try to get them to fix this as duplicate ID can create a very messy situation, at least notify them that the page is broken ;)

Answer (score 20):

Careful - `append()` will append HTML, and you may run into cross-site-scripting problems if you use it all the time and a user makes you `append('<script>alert("Hello")</script>')`.

Use `text()` to replace element content with text, or `append(document.createTextNode(x))` to append a text node.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

> The .append() method inserts the
>   specified content as the last child of
>   each element in the jQuery collection
>   (To insert it as the first child, use
>   .prepend()).

```
$("#tagscloud span").append(second);
$("#tagscloud span").append(third);
$("#tagscloud span").prepend(first);
```