# jQuery print variables in SPAN or P tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a variable to an HTML SPAN tag or a P tag.  I can show the variable in an INPUT tag with no problem.  I am not sure why I am having an issue showing the variable in any other tags.

```
 <script>
 $(function() 
 {
   $('.forecastedit'.click(function(e)
   {
     e.preventDefault();
     $uid = $(this).attr('data-uid');
     $service = $(this).attr('data-service');
     $pol = $(this).attr('data-pol');
     $('#uid').val($uid);  // also tried $('.uid').val($uid);
     $('#fcservice').val($service); // also tried $('#fcservice span').val($fcservice);
     $('#fcpol').val($pol);

     $('#forecastmodal').modal('show');
   });
 });
```

Here is the HTML that needs to be appended:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="forecastmodal">
 <div class="modal-content">
   // I have no problem getting the variables to print in the INPUT tags
   <input type="text" class="form-control uid" id="uid" />
   <input type="text" class="form-control fcservice" id="fcservice" />
   <input type="text" class="form-control fcpol" id="fcpol" />

   // These are the tags I would like to get the variable to print
   <span class="uid" id="uid"></span>
   <p class="service" id="service"></p>  // P tag just for example
    <span class="fcpol" id="fcpol"></span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

To reiterate, I want to be able to print out the JavaScript variables into SPAN tags or P tags rather than INPUT tags.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id`. `id` should always be unique

Comment: Well you *can* have the same ID more than once, but the behavior isn't guaranteed.  IIRC jQuery attempts to return the *first* object with that ID, but makes no promises.

Comment: span and p tags have no value. You could use .text() instead

Comment: `span` and `p` tags are not `input` tags (or textareas) and thus have no `value` property to assign

Comment: $('#uid').html(your_value);

Comment: It seems you have also a missing closing parentheses around the jQuery Object: `$('.forecastedit'.click(function(e)`

Comment: No `.forecastedit` element appears at `html` at Question ?

Comment: If you would create a jsfiddle I'm sure you would get more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input, textarea` etc. have the `value` attribute. Other tags like `span, div` etc. don't have that. You can use `.text("my text")` to insert the text into these elements

For more information:
[jQuery add text to span within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884021/jquery-add-text-to-span-within-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors with your script

1) the click listener is wrongly applied

2) you should not use more than one #id per page

3) `val()` is meant to be used with form elements

Hope this fiddle helps you http://jsfiddle.net/nyum4pLa/

Comment: Thank you for your input.  This would be off topic, but how does $('.forecastedit').on('click', function(e) differ from $('.forecastedit').click(function(e)?

Comment: Check the Jquey documentation here regarding those events
http://api.jquery.com/click/ vs http://api.jquery.com/on/